# Checking documents from MongoDb with if(==) operator in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications

I have problem how to check specific document from MongoDb in NodeJs with if operator.

My MongoDb collection looks liket this (I only need document "button"):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e95eb9da19c2430d4952754"),
    "title" : "Krepšinis",
    "author" : "5e90eb1abbcb1f33e8b17720",
    "place" : "dsadas",
    "count" : 10,
    "going_count" : 5,
    "button" : "Būsiu",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

My NodeJs:

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res){
  let post = {};
  if(post.button == "Būsiu"){
     post.button = "Nebūsiu";
  } else {
     post.button = "Būsiu";
  }


 let query = {_id:req.params.id}

 Post.update(query, post, function(err){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
     return;
   }
   req.flash('success', 'Postas Atnaujintas');
   res.send('Success');
  });
});
```

The problem is I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work.

And this is my Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.going').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('working')
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = ($target.attr('data-id'));
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '/posts/'+id,
      success: function(response){
      alert('Važiuojam');
      },
      error: function(err){
      console.log(err);
     }
    });
   });
  });
```

I don't really know what to try else, because I'm pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying the mongodb aggregation pipeline and check what the result  of affected documents in the query is as below

```
    router.post('/:id', function(req, res){
    let post= {};
    if(post.button == "Būsiu"){
    post.button = "Nebūsiu";
    } else {
     post.button = "Būsiu";
    }
    let query = {_id:req.params.id}
    Post.update(query, {$set:post}, function(err, response
    ){ 
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
     return;
    }
   console.log(response.result.nModified)
   req.flash('success', 'Postas Atnaujintas');
   res.send('Success');
    });
    });
```